# Operate with sql dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several related tables, in one of them I have a datatime field called CreateDate, in another table I have two also datatime fields called StartDate and EndDate.

The idea is to know if the CreateDate field of the first table is between the dates StartDate -3 (days) and EndDate, and based on whether or not it is in that date range to give value to a field in the first table.

How could I approach this case?

Thank you very much

Comment: We can't really give you any help unless you provide us with a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which would include the table schemas, sample data, and your previous attempts at solving the problem (What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?).

Comment: you would just use a between statement 
where createdate between (startdate -3) and enddate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MYSQL [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator
and the [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate)(`date` , INTERVAL 3 DAY)  function

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id    // ... do your join
WHERE (CreateDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(StartDate, INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND EndDate)
```